# Aerospike - WARN Failed to connect to peer errors in AQL

Tags: aerospike

When I try to run AQL I get a spam of the errors in my console below.

```
WARN Failed to connect to peer 192.168.12.51 3000. AEROSPIKE_ERR_TIMEOUT , 192.168.12.51:3000
WARN Failed to connect to peer **ANOTHER IP HERE**. AEROSPIKE_ERR_CLIENT Invalid proto type: 84 Expected: 1, **ANOTHER IP HERE**
WARN Failed to connect to peer 192.168.12.51 3000. AEROSPIKE_ERR_CONNECTION Socket write error: 113, 192.168.12.51:3000
***ABOVE 3 ERRORS KEEP REPEATING***
```

**My local IP is NOT 192.168.12.51**

From the looks of it, someone else is also running aerospike locally, and my machine is trying to connect to it.

I am unable to type any commands in AQL.

How do we stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run your aerospike on a different port? in config change from 3000 to say 3030?  then, all tools, aql etc, you just have to specify -p 3030 on the command line to go to the correct port.

Comment: I'll try that... One question - does aerospike try to connect to every other Aerospike node in LAN? for example, if I and another person run aerospike, would my aerospike automatically try to connect to his node?

Comment: You open a socket which is a 4-tuple ur ip, ur port, server ip, server port.  anyone client that knows server ip and port will connect to it. this is one instance of aerospike running. if you want to run two instances of aerospike process on same server, then you have to separate by ports and if you want, you can form a cluster or keep them two separate standalone "sinlge node clusters". Look and understand the configuration file. If you register your CE download, you get access to free intro class. Consider doing that. It goes over the basic concepts in couple of hours. Worth it.